# Does adjusted R-square seek to estimate fixed score or random score population r-squared?

Tags: regression, estimation, r-squared

Population r-square $\rho^2$ can be defined assuming fixed scores or random scores:

- Fixed scores: The sample size and the particular values of the predictors are held fixed. Thus, $\rho^2_f$ is the proportion of variance explained in the outcome by the population regression equation when the predictor values are held constant.
- Random scores: The particular values of the predictors are drawn from a distribution. Thus, $\rho^2_r$ refers to the proportion of variance explained in the outcome in the population where the predictor values correspond to the population distribution of the predictors.

I've previously asked about [whether this distinction makes much difference to estimates of $\rho^2$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63194/how-different-are-fixed-score-and-random-score-regression-estimates-of-populatio). I've also asked generally about [how to calculate an unbiased estimate of  $\rho^2$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55929/what-is-an-unbiased-estimate-of-population-r-square).

I can see that as the sample size gets larger the distinction between fixed-score and random-score gets less important. However, I'm trying to confirm whether adjusted $R^2$ is designed to estimate fixed score or random score $\rho^2$.

#### Questions

- **Is adjusted $R^2$  designed to estimate fixed score or random score $\rho^2$?**
- **Is there a principled explanation of how the formula for adjusted r-square relates to one or other form of $\rho^2$?**

#### Background to my confusion

When I read Yin and Fan (2001, p.206) they write:

> One of the basic assumptions of the multiple regression model is that
>   the values of the independent variables are known constants and are
>   fixed by the researcher before the experiment. Only the dependent
>   variable is free to vary from sample to sample. That regression model
>   is called the *fixed linear regression model*.
>
> However, in social and
>   behavioral sciences, the values of independent variables are rarely
>   fixed by the researchers and are also subject to random errors.
>   Therefore, a second regression model for applications has been
>   suggested, in which both dependent and independent variables are
>   allowed to vary (Binder, 1959; Park & Dudycha, 1974). That model is
>   called the random model (or correction model). Although the maximum
>   likelihood estimates of the regression coefficients obtained from the
>   random and fixed models are the same under normality assumptions,
>   their distributions are very different. The random model is so complex
>   that more research is needed before it can be accepted in place of the
>   commonly used fixed linear regression model. Therefore, the fixed
>   model is usually applied, even when the assumptions are not met
>   completely (Claudy, 1978). Such applications of the fixed regression
>   model with assumptions violated would cause "overfitting," because the
>   random error introduced from the less-than-perfect sample data tends
>   to be capitalized in the process. As a result, the sample multiple
>   correlation coefficient obtained that way tends to overestimate the
>   true population multiple correlation (Claudy, 1978; Cohen & Cohen,
>   1983; Cummings, 1982).

So I wasn't clear whether the above statement is saying that adjusted $R^2$ compensates for error introduced by the random model or whether this was just a caveat in the paper flagging the existence of the random model, but that the paper was going to focus on the fixed model.

#### References

- Yin, P., & Fan, X. (2001). Estimating $R^2$ shrinkage in multiple regression: A comparison of different analytical methods. The Journal of Experimental Education, 69(2), 203-224. [PDF](http://www.statpt.com/applied_gen/yin_2001.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

Raju et al  (1997) note that

> Pedhazur (1982) and Mitchell & Klimoski (1986) have argued that results are
>   relatively unaffected by the model [fixed-x or random-x] selected when Ns are at 
>   least of moderate size (approximately 50).

Nonetheless, Raju et al (1997) classify some adjusted $R^2$ formulas for estimating $\rho^2$ as "Fixed X formulas" and "Random X formulas".

**Fixed X formulas:**
Several formulas are mentioned including the formula proposed by Ezekiel (1930) which is standard in most statistical software:

$$\hat{\rho}_{(E)}^2 = 1 - \frac{N-1}{N-p-1}(1-R^2)$$

Thus, the short answer to the question is **the standard adjusted $R^2$ formula typically reported and built into standard statistical software is an estimate of fixed-x $\rho^2$.**

**Random X formulas:**

Olkin and Pratt (1958) proposed a formula

$$\hat{ \rho}^2 _{(OP)} = 1 - \left[ {\frac{{N - 3}}{{N - p - 1}}} \right](1 - {R^2})F\left[ {1,1;\frac{{N - p + 1}}{2};(1 - {R^2})} \right]$$
 where F is the [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Raju et al (1997) explain how various other formulas, such as Pratt's and Herzberg's "are approximations to the expected hypergeometric function". E.g., Pratt's formula is

$${\hat \rho}^2_{(P)} = 1 - \frac{{(N - 3)(1 - {R^2})}}{{N - p - 1}}\left[ {1 + \frac{{2(1 - {R^2})}}{{N - p - 2.3}}} \right]$$

**How do estimates differ?**
Leach and Hansen (2003)  report present a nice table showing the effect of different formulas on a sample of different published datasets in psychology (see Table 3).
The mean Ezekiel $R^2_{adj}$ was .2864 compared to Olkin and Pratt $R^2_{adj}$ of .2917 and Pratt $R^2_{adj}$ of .2910. As per Raju et al's initial quotation about the distinction between fixed and random-x formulas being most relevant to small sample sizes, Leach and Hansen's table shows how the difference between Ezekiel's fixed-x formula and Olkin and Pratt's random-x formula is most prominent in small sample sizes, particularly those less than 50.

#### References

- Leach, L. F., & Henson, R. K. (2003). The use and impact of adjusted R2 effects in published regression research. In annual meeting of the Southwest Educational Research Assocation, San Antonio, TX. [PDF](http://mlrv.ua.edu/2007/Vol33_1/Leach-Henson-p1-11.pdf)
- Mitchell, T. W., & Klimoski, R. J. (1986). Estimating the validity of cross-validity estimation. *Journal of Applied Psychology, 71*, 311-317.
- Pedhazur, E. J. (1982). Multiple Regression in Behavioral Research (2nd ed.) New York: Holt, Rinehart, and Winston.
- Raju, N. S., Bilgic, R., Edwards, J. E., & Fleer, P. F. (1997). Methodology review: Estimation of population validity and cross-validity, and the use of equal weights in prediction. Applied Psychological Measurement, 21(4), 291-305.